# ProgressDialog : how to prevent Leaked Window

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progressdialog

I'm using ProgressDialog to prevent the user from interacting while the device is downloading stuff from internet.

everything was working fine until my client managed to produce this bug :

```
"07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821): Activity android.pixelrain.framework.PixelRainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@463f3e50 that was originally added here
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity android.pixelrain.framework.PixelRainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@463f3e50 that was originally added here
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:251)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.HTTPHelper.DraftHelper.getDraft(DraftHelper.java:70)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.online.OnlineRetriver.getDraft(OnlineRetriver.java:312)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.HTTPHelper.DraftButtonGL.loadDraft(DraftButtonGL.java:72)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.HTTPHelper.DraftButtonGL.isTouched(DraftButtonGL.java:89)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.opengl.views.game.QuickStartGL.touchEnded(QuickStartGL.java:160)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.game.GameHandler.onTouchEvent(GameHandler.java:277)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.pixelrain.opengl.GLSurfaceViewChipmunk.onTouchEvent(GLSurfaceViewChipmunk.java:27)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3765)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1701)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2093)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1685)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-06 17:10:50.363: ERROR/WindowManager(8821):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

and I have no idea how to fix this.

any ideas what causes this and how to solve it ?

The log traces back the error to this line :

```
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PixelRainActivity.staticThis, "",PixelRainActivity.staticThis.getResources().getString( R.string.draftProgressMessage), true);
```

would it solve the problem if I changed it to this :

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PixelRainActivity.staticThis, "",PixelRainActivity.staticThis.getResources().getString( R.string.draftProgressMessage), true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and it only occured when I was opening a `Dialog`/`ProcessDialog` when the activity was paused. Is that the case?

Comment: Or may be while changing orientations?

Comment: Please update the accepted answer to be to use `dismiss`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The leak comes probably from your `PixelRainActivity.staticThis` attribute. If you’re keeping a reference to an activity, even after that this activity has been destroyed, you have a memory leak.

The easiest way to fix is to use the application’s `Context` instead. Change your `staticThis = this` line in the method `onCreate()` to `staticThis = this.getApplicationContext()` and it should work (and change the type of `staticThis` to `Context` if this is not already the case)

Comment: didn't work for me. I am using progressDialog.show() in Async task's onPreExecute(). and i get: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: In order to create Dialog, you have to pass not Context, but Activity. So, this.getApplicationContext() is not correct

Comment: According to this, using getApplicationContext will throw an error in this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi

Comment: -1 @Guillaume Brunerie - You have to pass an Activity instance as a context ,bcz that operation is conducted in UI.So passing getApplicationContext() will lead to an exception.

Answer (score 119):

Use:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

in end work

Comment: I was wrongly calling hide and not dismiss(). Thank you.

Comment: To add the the answer: you probably should call `progressDialog.dismiss()` in `onDestroy()` (but before calling `super.onDestroy()`)

Answer (score 5):

There are situations when you have to verify in `onDetach` or in `onDestroy` if the progress dialog is still visible.
Like so:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

cygnus has a good idea to use showDialog(MY_INT), where MY_INT is just some constant value you choose just to distinguish it from any other similar dialogs you launch that way. You take it down the same way with dismissDialog(MY_INT). Just don't launch it from your onPause method. You may want to do that instead from the the onResume method of the activity the user is going to. Then you override that activity's onCreateDialog method like this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id == MY_INT) {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Your message string");
        return progressDialog;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `ProgressDialog.show()`, try using

`Activity.showDialog()` which should automatically manage the `Dialog` for you and prevent leaks.

EDIT: When you call `showDialog(int)`, it will trigger `Activity.onCreateDialog(int)` where you can create the `Dialog` you want and return the `Dialog` you want to display.

Comment: but whit Activity.showDialog() I need to pass the an ID to a dialog, how then do display the progress dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with a progress dialog and a background task.  The AsyncTask (http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html) allowed me to do both much more cleanly and without the leaked window.

Comment: that link is a dead end

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any `thread` or `AsyncTask` and downloading stuff from internet and showing `progress bar` , you should use `DialogFragment` or cancel progress `dialog` when `Activity` get stop also if you are showing progress in `Asynctask` fist cancel `Asynctask` and override `oncancel` callback method and `dismiss` progress dialogue there.

`Window leak` in `Activity` or `fragment` is actually occurs due to you are trying to add a window and while it shows up it is on the `foreground`,but when you are pressing the home it gets paused and then gets stopped via the `onStop`(). So your `CustomView` remains attached to the window that now has disappeared.Hence according to the system your `customView` occupied the space which it did not release.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use an `AsyncTask` to get something from internet in the background. And there is no need to pass a static context though. And activity

```
new YourAsyncTask(context).execute();
```

Call AsyncTask like above

```
private class YourAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
 private Context context;
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 //pass context in constructor
  public YourAsynTask(Context context)
  {
     this.context = context;
  }

  //show progress in onPre 
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
    //show Progress code here.
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
  }

  //dismiss Progress dialog in onPost
  @Override 
  protected void OnPostExecute(String response)
  {
    if(progressDialog!=null)
     progressDialog.dismiss();
     progressDialog = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the cancel() method when another activity comes into the foreground.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   this.mProgress.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was gettin this exception

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();//at this line
        showProgressDialog();
    }
```

This fix worked for me:

```
  @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            showProgressDialog();
            super.onResume();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `progressDialog.dismiss()` before the activity gets killed. I got mine fixed like this.

Comment: Better put a check if activity is alive by `activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()` before showing the progress dialog